# Changing root folder name

Tags: url

I would like to change the root folder name where my Craft install is currently at.  for example: website.com/dev to website.com/draft1.  When changing the folder name on my server and the site URL in the Craft admin settings to match, I get an error.  What am I missing?  Will I need to reinstall Craft from scratch under the new URL?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

No need to go through the installation process again.

I assume that `/dev` is a folder under your public html folder that Craft's public index.php file lives in.

So Craft's index.php lives in something like:

```
/path/to/public_html/dev/index.php
```

And what you want to do is change the site to live in:

```
/path/to/public_html/draft1/index.php
```

If that's the case, you'd just need to move anything in the `public_html/dev` folder over to `public_html/draft1` and update your `siteUrl`.  That's either been defined in your `craft/config/general.php` file or under Settings->General in the control panel, depending on how your site is setup.

If you've defined any custom environment paths in `craft/config/general.php`, they might need to be updated as well.